# Парсинг значения json с помощью Newtonsoft на с#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Задача: получить значение "lastPriceProtected".

С мопощью ClientWebSocket получаю json, он различный:

ответ 1

```
{"table":"instrument","action":"update","data":[{"symbol":"XBTUSD","lastTickDirection":"ZeroMinusTick","timestamp":"2018-03-22T20:15:45.258Z"}]}
```

ответ 2

```
{"table":"instrument","action":"update","data":[{"symbol":"XBTUSD","lastPrice":8569,"lastPriceProtected":8569.7146,"lastChangePcnt":-0.0362,"timestamp":"2018-03-22T20:15:45.350Z"}]}
```

по этому однозначно получить значение "lastPriceProtected" не получается так как в первой строке данного параметра нет.
т.е. как бы я не формировал поиск поля постоянно получаю исключение: "System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.""

мой код:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(str);
JToken firstProductNames = o["data"].SelectToken("lastPriceProtected");
```

=======================================================================
после чтения документации и нескольких попыток получил рабочий код, спасибо всем кто помогал.

```
            JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(str);
            if (o1["data"] != null)
            {
                var firstProductNames = o1["data"].Value<JArray>().ElementAt(0).SelectToken("lastPriceProtected");
                if (firstProductNames != null)
                {
                    float value = firstProductNames.Value<float>();
                    Debug.WriteLine(value + "--1");
                }
            }
```

if (o1["data"] != null) проверка нужна чтобы не получать исключения.

Comment: на какой конкретно строчке падает?

Comment: на 2 строке кода

Comment: А если так обращаться: `o["data"]["lastPriceProtected"]`?

Comment: Тоже самое исключение

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Советую вам создать  полноценную структуру данных, некий класс, где будут все возможные значения из вашего `JSON`.

То есть, возьмем 2-ой `JSON` и сделаем два класса:

```
public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("symbol")]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lastPrice")]
    public long LastPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lastPriceProtected")]
    public double LastPriceProtected { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lastChangePcnt")]
    public double LastChangePcnt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
    public System.DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("table")]
    public string Table { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("action")]
    public string Action { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Data[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

Как можно заметить, тут имеются все возможные значения приведенные в красивый вид с красивыми именами.

Далее нам надо десериализовать данные:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);
```

Все, можно работать. Все данные, которые имеются в `JSON` - будут занесены в переменные, а те, которые пустые - будут иметь стандартные значения (то есть `null`, `0`, `false` и т.д.). Если не хотим путаться и не заполненные данные хотите получить в `NULL` значение, то можете добавить знак `?` после типа (к примеру `public double LastPriceProtected { get; set; }` меняем на `public double? LastPriceProtected { get; set; }`).

Ну теперь простейший вывод:

```
foreach (var value in json.Data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value.LastPriceProtected); //Либо делаем проверку на необходимо на NULL/стандартное значение.
}
```

На выходе получим `0`, либо значение (в вашем случае это `8569,7146`).

---

По поводу минимализма и практичности...

**1. Использование `JObject`:**

Маленькое приложение, где мы выводим различные данные (как в основном "теле" программы, так и в другом классе):

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class SumData
    {
        private JObject Json;

        public SumData(JObject json)
        {
            Json = json;
        }

        public int Sum()
        {
            return (int) Json["data"]["valOne"] + (int) Json["data"]["valOne"];
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static JObject json;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string jString = "...";
            json = JObject.Parse(jString);

            Console.WriteLine(json["Hello"]);
            ListedObjects();


            SumData sumData = new SumData(json);
            Console.WriteLine(sumData.Sum());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void ListedObjects()
        {
            foreach (var val in json["Collection"])
            {
                Console.WriteLine(val["dataObject"]);
                Console.WriteLine(val["dataObject2"]);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

К примеру на сервере изменилась структура, все данные переименовались. Что делать? Выход - искать где крашется приложение и руками изменять **все** значения.

Минусы такого подхода в том, что вы не получите ошибку, пока не вызовите эти данные. То есть вы можете что то упустить при редактирование, да и кода править придется много.

Плюсы такого подхода:

- Не нужна структура классов.

Минусы:

- Мы не знаем имена, которые нам доступны, забудем - беда..
- Трудно редактировать в коде.
- Если что то поменялось на сервер, то мы не узнаем это, пока не вызовем. То есть нам трудно будет отловить все переменные, можем где то забыть переименовать и среда разработки нам об этом не скажет.
- Не очень понятные имена, зачастую сервера дают значения вида `o`, `h`.

**2. Использование `Структуры классов`:**

Точно такая же задача, все точно такое же, но с классами:

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class RootJson
    {
        public string Hello { get; set; }
        public Collection[] Collection { get; set; }
        public Data Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Collection
    {
        [JsonProperty("jsonServerValue")]
        public int dataObject { get; set; }
        public int dataObject2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public int valOne { get; set; }
        public int valTwo { get; set; }
    }

    public class SumData
    {
        private RootJson Json;

        public SumData(RootJson json)
        {
            Json = json;
        }

        public int Sum()
        {
            return Json.Data.valOne + Json.Data.valTwo;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static RootJson json;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string jString = "...";
            json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootJson>(jString);

            Console.WriteLine(json.Hello);
            ListedObjects();


            SumData sumData = new SumData(json);
            Console.WriteLine(sumData.Sum());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void ListedObjects()
        {
            foreach (var val in json.Collection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(val.dataObject);
                Console.WriteLine(val.dataObject2);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Что имеем? Если сервер поменяет структуру, то нам достаточно поменять пару строк в нашем классе, либо вовсе с помощью `[JsonProperty("...")]` мы можем указать имя переменной и нечего не трогать.

Плюсы такого подхода:

- Тип, мы его сразу знаем, не надо сто раз конвертировать.
- Если поменяются данные, то не потеряетесь при изменение, среда разработки подскажет что и где не так.
- Удобные имена.
- Удобное использование.
- Знаем все доступные переменные, не надо вспоминать имя.

Минусы:

- Ну, может быть большая "портянка" из структуры классов, но ИМХО, положил в файлик .cs да забыл.

Comment: Основательно к делу подошли =D

Comment: если бы я получал однозначно одни и тежи поля, то да можно было бы создать класс.

Comment: @АртурШмаков Я же вам в ответе ясно сказал, даже если вы будете получать **не все данные**, то структура классов не разрушится и вы просто будете иметь нулевые значения. Вам достаточно один раз заполнить **полную** структуру и дальше удобно с ней работать. Ведь не удобно писать `json["data1"]["data2"]["data3"]`, удобней же `json.Data1.Data2.Data3` (но это мое лично мнение, может вы любитель извращений)) )

Comment: @Suvitruf Я думаю, что надо сразу делать правильно, а как по мне - парсить `JSON` правильней именно классами. Если это конечно не ответ сервера с одним значением `success`.

Comment: Дело не в извращениях, дело в переносимости кода и читабельности. если мне понадобится использовать данный код в другом проекте мне нужно будет менять классы, вместо смены имён. + я любитель минимализма. А так я согласен ваш код основателен и более правильный.

Comment: @АртурШмаков И где легче? К примеру у вас json используется в 5-ти классах и в них, в 3-ех разных методах. При изменение/добавление чего то на сервере - вам придется менять все `json["data1"]` переменные на нужные и заместо изменения/добавления 1 строки в класс - вам нужно будет очень много строк кода проверить и исправить. У вас же этот класс со структурой будет лежать в одном месте и его просто вызываете.

Comment: я пулучаю разлычные данные в разных структурах json, и даже если я сделаю класс со всеми возможными вариантами а их очень много, что мешает моему серверу добавить другой json который у меня не предусмотрен. тогда всё сломается. или я не прав.

Comment: Почему не использовать Nullable-свойства?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не всегда json легко на классы ложится. Мне в текущем проекте кучу кастомных конвертеров приходится писать. То ещё удовольствие.

Comment: @АртурШмаков Я дополнил ответ, указав плюсы и минусы вариантов (не все конечно, но все же). То, что вы указали в вопросе - это у вас одна структура данных, не две, вы лишь получаете ее в одном варианте полную, а в другом не полную. Не обязательно делать "все доступные варианты", если они вам не нужны. Будет правильней "все используемые варианты".  Если ваш сервер начнет выдавать другие данные, то как я указал в ответе, легче будет поменять структуру, чем везде искать и править имена, а среда разработки вам не даст ошибиться и подскажет, где вы изменили переменную, это в разы удобней!

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я указал в ответе, что их можно использовать. Тут зависит от того, что именно удобней автору, получать нули, либо `null`.

Comment: @Suvitruf Согласен, но лучше грамотно это все реализовать и засунуть в классы, чем потом мучатся и выявлять, где мы неверно указали имя `JToken`'a. У меня в проектах бывало, что функция вызывалась довольно редко и при редактирование всех `JToken`'ов я упускал имена - итог, пол недели тратил для того, что бы отловить все ошибки. А со структурой (хот в нее бывает и трудно засунуть), таких ошибок не совершишь. И это очень удобная вещь)

Answer (score 2):

У вас:

```
"data":[{"symbol":"XBTUSD","lastPrice":8569,"lastPriceProtected":8569.7146,"lastChangePcnt":-0.0362,"timestamp":"2018-03-22T20:15:45.350Z"}]
```

массив, а вы пытаетесь работать как с объектом.

Надо так:

```
JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(str);
JToken firstProductNames = o1["data"].Value<JArray>().GetItem(0).SelectToken("lastPriceProtected");
if (firstProductNames != null) {
    float value = firstProductNames.Value<float>();
}
```

Comment: поделитесь кодом как мне в таком случае обращаться?

Comment: @АртурШмаков обновил ответ.

Comment: сейчас выводит ошибку на GetItem.
Ошибка CS0122 'JContainer.GetItem(int)" недоступен из-за его уровня защиты.

Comment: А не проще тут тогда нечто подобное сделать - `JToken val = json["data"][0]["lastPriceProtected"];`?