# Достать значение из массива Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json

```
 var Request = new HttpRequest();
 string Response = Request.Get("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?fields=photo_50&access_token=" + Form1.access_token + "&v=5.80").ToString();
 dynamic json = JObject.Parse(Response);
```

Получаемый ответ:

```
{  
   "response":[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "first_name":"fName",
         "last_name":"lName",
         "photo_50":"https://pp.userapi.com/photo.jpg"
      }
   ]
}
```

Собственно, сабж, как из массива response вытянуть id, first_name, last_name и photo_50?

**Решение**:

```
 var Request = new HttpRequest();
 string Response = Request.Get("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?fields=photo_50&access_token=" + Form1.access_token + "&v=5.80").ToString();

 var Parse = Welcome.FromJson(Response);
 foreach(var value in Parse.Response)
      {
        label6.Text = value.Id;
        label4.Text = value.FirstName;
        label5.Text = value.LastName;
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = value.Photo50;
      }
```

где Welcome - класс, взятый [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/803955/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-json-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-newtonsoft-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81). Но сам код взят с [этого](https://app.quicktype.io/#r=json2csharp) сайта, где вы должны вставить свой json-ответ и получить код.

Comment: [пользуйтесь поиском, вы дублируете тему!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/803955/Парсинг-значения-json-с-помощью-newtonsoft-на-с)

Comment: @VladimirT Тревогнули как дубликат и отменили? Или просто руками набрали текст? Мгм.

Comment: Для ВК есть публичная библиотека: [VkNet](https://github.com/vknet/vk)

Comment: @AK, ручками набил сообщение. :) а потом тревогу отправил.